# Installing MobileFirst Platform Studio fails

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

When trying to install MFP 7.0 eclipse plugin from eclipse marketplace the following error is displayed:

Eclipse version 4.4.1

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
    session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
    Unable to read repository at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mfpsupdate/plugins/com.worklight.worklight-artifacts_7.0.0.00-20150608-1356.jar.
    Read timed out
```

Comment: Yes, I tried several times and it is still failing...But other eclipse plugins are being installed without any problem

Comment: Can you check if that URL is accessible from your machine at all? For example, what happens if you try to access it directly from a browser?

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, "Read time out" - there is a network time out... we can't do anything about it, you will have to try again at a later time.

Comment: Still not working...and it´s not a network problem since it is possible to install other eclipse plugins